# Help in Streaming Video from IP Camera in android

Tags: android, streaming, live

Dear All:
 i am making an application in which we can connect wireless IP camera with my android mobile and then can get images from the IP camera in my application 
please guide me through any tutorial that how to get connected to external hardware or to an IP camera through android application 
please guide me through some code snippet or any tutorial.. for connecting my android with IP camera

Thanks 
waiting...........

Comment: Why don't you write what protocol and video encoding you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the IP Camera Streams using MJPEG (Motion JPEG), You will need to create a motion jpeg decoder (its simple, check out these sources http://www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/)